# How to create a C# WinForm TreeView to automatically select the parent node when child node selected?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to develop a C# Windows Form with a tree view. Actually i want to implement an interface toallow / disallow privileges for specific users.
I use a tree view to show menu bar hierarchy and sys admin can check or uncheck the privileges. 
This is my tree view

[image: This]

In this image, if I checked Professionals => Services => **Add** checkbox, Professionals & Services check boxes should be partially checked like this image

[image]

The thing i want to do is, If I selected a child branch, The parent branch should be partially checked.

How to customize tree view to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: It is technically possible, you have to derive your own class from TreeView and override CreateParams to turn on the TVS_EX_PARTIALCHECKBOXES style.  And add a method that uses SendMessage() to send TVM_SETITEMSTATE.

Answer (score 0):

TreeView doesn't have three state checkbox 
look here i think here u can solve your problem :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6549/Tri-State-TreeView-Control